# How do I query Azure DevOps (TFS) using curl.exe or PowerShell directly without additional support libraries?

Tags: windows, azure-devops, tfs

Azure DevOps has a REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

How do I access it using curl.exe or PowerShell without additional support libraries?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Comment: Yes.  The documentation for the REST API doesn't show you how to access the API using curl.exe and PowerShell.  If you want to point me to the Microsoft documentation that shows that, that'd be great.

Comment: Did you do any additional research? A quick search of Stack Overflow showed me this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472498/need-to-encode-pat-to-use-it-in-rest-api-for-azure-devops-in-a-bash-script-stru, which includes instructions for using `curl`.

Comment: @DanielMann those wouldn't make sense to Windows programmers.  This is specifically for curl.exe in Windows.  Plus, some people prefer to use PowerShell on Windows.

Comment: Adam The Automater hs an excellent article on [Working with REST APIs and PowerShell’s Invoke-RestMethod](https://adamtheautomator.com/invoke-restmethod/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instructions are for Windows, although they can be used in other platforms with slight modification.

Below, replace with your own values for:

- `{organization}`
- `{project}`
- `{team}`
- `{pat}`

You can create a PAT in your organization's portal.  Using your browser, go to: (replace `{organization}`):

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_usersSettings/tokens
```

###### Using Command Prompt

If using Command Prompt (cmd.exe), `curl.exe` can be used.  It is part of Windows (10+).  Also works in PowerShell, but you have to spell out `curl.exe`, not just `curl`.  The commands below output the results to the console.  You can pipe it to a file, or use the `-o` option in curl to specify a file to output to.

###### Using PoowerShell

If using PowerShell, you use the `Invoke-RestMethod` command.  In the below commands, the result of the command is placed in a variable, `$result`, which you can use after the invocation.
The commands below also assume variables `$pat` and `$header` are initialized as follows:

```
$pat = "{pat}"
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)")))"}
```

##### Example getting a work item by ID ([Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item)):

###### Using curl:

```
curl.exe -u :{pat} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}
```

###### Using PowerShell:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}"
$entries = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
```

Quick display of the above output:

```
$entries.Fields | Format-Table system.workitemtype, system.title
```

Comment: When using REST Method PUT you need to create a Body as well, see this excellent article for more help [Open Tech Guides - How to call Azure Devops REST API from PowerShell](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/azure/201/devops-rest-powershell.html)